# manipulating textbox variables in calculations

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I have some code where I am trying to use variables in a tabpage. The first tabpage only has one text box for user entry (miles.text) and a button to do a calculation: traveltime = mileage/speed. The value from miles.text is stored into a variable called mileage while the speed used is stored in a variable called speed (me.speedtextbox.text).

Ordinarily, doing val(variable.text) works like a charm and it's not doing it in this case. When the user enters 100 for the mileage, it should be divided by 65 (the number in the database) and, therefore, the answer should be 1.53 hours. In my case, I'm getting "infinity" and whenever I do anything else with the variable, I get "when casting from a number, the value must be a number less than infinity." But it is! It's only 65 and I double-checked that the dataset said that too, which it does. Not sure why I am getting this error...thank you!

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Property Traveltime As Decimal

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'fooDataSet.testdata' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TestdataTableAdapter.Fill(Me.foouDataSet.testdata)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim mileage As Integer
        Dim speed As Integer


        mileage = Val(miles.Text)
        speed = Val(Me.SpeedTextBox.Text)
        traveltime = mileage / speed

        txttraveltime.text = Traveltime.ToString

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtrate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txttraveltime.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

So I did a test program where it did only one thing and that was to simply read one data column in a one row database and store it to a local variable and multiply it by 1.60  except now I am getting "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference" and it doesn't seem to recognize Me.Speed when I declare it. What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Speed As Object
    Dim Me.Speed As New Speed

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Me.Speed = CDec(fooDataSet.testdataRow.Item("speed"))*1.60
        Speedtextbox.text = Me.Speed.tostring

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'fooDataSet.testdata' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TestdataTableAdapter.Fill(Me.fooDataSet.testdata)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what the problem was.

To store a field from a one-line database to a local variable for calculations, apparently it has to happen in the form1_load event, after the dataadapter fill statement, like so:

```
Me.TestdataTableAdapter.Fill(Me.foouDataSet.testdata)
  speed = Me.fooDataSet.testdata(0).speed
```

and just DIM speed as Decimal after the Public Class line. The same could be done for any other field you want to work with in a similar kind of single datarow:

```
yourvarname = Me.yourdatasetname.yourtablename(0).the_database_field_you_want_to_fetch
```

(Wow! Did I just write something textbooky? LOL)

Then, after the button click, to do a calculation, it is:

```
traveltime = CDec(miles.Text/ speed) 
txttraveltime.Text = traveltime.ToString
```

making sure to DIM traveltime as Decimal.

Works! The problem was the (0) to indicate row 0 (because it's only one row.) Thank you everyone for your help, especially Competent_Tech. I learned something and I'm happy that I could get back to you guys and share.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything else, you should do the following:

1. Open the project's properties (right-click on the Project, then select `Properties`)
2. Click on the `Compile` tab (left-hand side)
3. Select `All Configurations` from the dropdown menu
4. Select `On` from the `Option Explicit` menu.
5. Select `On` from the `Option Strict` menu.
6. Save the project

This will more than likely cause a lot of errors to be displayed, but fixing these errors will substantially improve your application's health.

Now, that that is done, the following code will fix the problems in the button click:

```
    Dim mileage As Integer
    Dim speed As Integer

    If IsNumeric(Me.Miles.Text) Then
        mileage = CInt(Me.Miles.Text)
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Me.SpeedTextBox.Text) Then
        speed = CInt(Me.SpeedTextBox.Text)
    End If

    If speed <> 0 Then
        Traveltime = CDec(mileage / speed)
    Else
        Traveltime = 0
    End If

    txtTravelTime.Text = Traveltime.ToString
```

However, the code as you have it will produce correct results, so there must be something else amiss. Try the above first and if there are still issues, you can update your question with the details.

Comment: Instead, is there a way that I can say something like tabpage2.speedtextbox.text = foodataset.testdata.speed and store it like that since I'm reading the data from a database that only has one row (it's one of 20 fields)? Not sure.

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely load the values directly into the textboxes. But remember that you don't need the `tabpage2` in front of the textbox.

Comment: Since the database only has one row and I want to get one field from it, would I write something like Me.speed = Me.foodataset.testdata.speed since the field name in the MDB file is exactly speed and, therefore, keep the names similar and declare it as an integer?

Comment: I'm trying to master how to write a DIM statement to pluck items from a single row. For example, I want to store mpg to Me.mpg but I see that I'll have to use something like Dim row As DataRow = fooDataSet.testdataRow.Equals.item("mpg") and apparently I have too many arguments in this line. I'm thinking something along these lines will fix my problem but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: You are very close: `Me.Mpg = CDec(fooDataSet.testdataRow("mpg"))`. The `Item` property returns the value of the column with the specified name and since this is the default property for the DataRow, you can use the shortcut above. You could also write it as: `Me.Mpg = CDec(fooDataSet.testdataRow.Item("mpg"))`

Comment: Added it, made it a member of Form1 by generating a property stub. Now it says "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference". So I declared it as an object (Private Property mpg as object.) MSDN says when you get an error like this to "reference the instance by a variable name" so I'm not sure what implication that has for my variable me.mpg.

Comment: I added code to show what is happening. I feel like I'm so close. Thanks in advance for your help. I've tried reading different things on MSDN and other places but I'm not seeing anything that comes close to what I'm trying to do, which seems so simple in my mind (read a file, grab a number, play with it lol.)

Comment: Ok, I see the issue in the new code: remove both of your dim statements at the top of the form and replace them with the following: `Dim Speed As Decimal`

Comment: I'm still getting the reference error and it's underlining what is contained in the CDec statement as the problem. When I tested and put a "Me." in front of the dataset name, it didn't remove the reference problem so I changed it back. When I put in CDec(Object in front of the where the data is, it says my dataset is not part of object and suggested the name of the program (rating)...hence, CDec(rating.foodataset....) and then I thought, ok, I'll Dim rating as object. Boom! The reference error went away BUT now I'm being told to dim another variable as new. I'm really stuck!

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the calculation in a separate class and then use object-binding. Here is how the travel time calculator would look like:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class TraveltimeCalculator
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _miles As Double
    Public Property Miles() As Double
        Get
            Return _miles
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            If _miles <> value Then
                _miles = value
                OnPropertyChanged("Miles")
                OnPropertyChanged("Traveltime")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _speed As Double
    Public Property Speed() As Double
        Get
            Return _speed
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            If _speed <> value Then
                _speed = value
                OnPropertyChanged("Speed")
                OnPropertyChanged("Traveltime")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Traveltime() As Double
        Get
            Return If(_speed = 0.0, 0.0, _miles / _speed)
        End Get
    End Property

#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged Members"

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
     Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

In Visual Studio, add a data source in the Data Sources panel. Choose "Object" and then select the `TraveltimeCalculator` (it has to be compiled, before you can do that). Now you can drag the speed, mileage and travel time fields from the data sources panel to your form. All the wire-up will happen automatically. VS automatically inserts a BindingSource and a navigator into your form. You will not need the navigator and can safely remove it. The only thing you still have to do is to add the following code in the form load event handler or in the form constructor:

```
Private Sub frmTravelTime_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TraveltimeCalculatorBindingSource.DataSource = New TraveltimeCalculator()
End Sub
```

When you enter speeds and mileages, the travel time textbox will automatically be updated. Non-numeric entries will automatically be rejected and all the text-number conversions happen automatically.